# Listen to Android app's traffic using Fiddler

Tags: android, fiddler

I'm working on an Android app on a non-rooted phone. It uses the network to download some data from a server using HTTP. I would like to debug the stream of those information, so I installed Fiddler and followed some tutorials like:

- http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/ConfigureForAndroid
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2013/04/03/configuring-fiddler-to-be-a-proxy-for-android-emulators.aspx

The problem is that this methods work only if the data is sent and received by the Android Browser, while apps are totally ignored. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I managed to see my app's traffic by using an emulator, not a real phone. The guide from MSDN (second link) is the most appropriate for this task.

Comment: 2020 and I'm having the same problem. On the device, I can use device browser and view http and https traffic in fiddler on windows pc but get an SSLhandshakeexception error when I try https from my app.